# Recursion with strings

Tags: recursion

Let $A$ be a set of strings on the alphabet ${a, b}$ starting with $a$ and ending with $b$ and they don't have occurrences of $ba$ as a substring. For example, $abab ̸∉ A$, $ab ∈ A$, $abb ∈ A$, $aabab ̸∉ A$, $aaab ∈ A$.

(i) Provide a recursive definition of A.

My attempt:

Base: $λ∈A$ (empty string)

Recursive Passage: ?

Please exaplin me how to do it.

Comment: Recognize that they are all of the form (several a's)(several b's).,  e.g. aaabb, or aabbbb, or abbbbbb.  The only question is how many $a$'s and how many $b$'s there are.  Note further, the emptystring does not satisfy the condition that it begins with $a$... the smallest string in your set is the string $ab$.

Comment: As for coming up with a recursive definition... again, $ab$ is the smallest string in the collection.  Any other string can be formed by adding some $a$'s to the beginning or adding some $b$'s to the end.

Answer (score 1):

The empty string is *not* in $A$, since any element of $A$ must start with $a$, and end with $b$.

A recursive specification for $A$ can be given as follows . . .

- $ab\in A$.$\\[4pt]$

  If $x\in A$, then $ax\in A$, and $xb\in A$.

Comment: What is the string x?

Comment: An arbitrary element of $A$.

Comment: But if the arbitrary element is $a$ then $ax$ is not correct... ?

Comment: But $a$ is _not_ an element of $A$. It's _recursive_; to apply the rule, $x$ must already be an element of $A$.

Comment: The elements of A are a and b, x is either a or b

Comment: No, the elements of the _alphabet_ are the symbols $a$ and $b$. By the specified rules, neither of the strings $a$ or $b$ is in $A$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78738/discussion-between-user565089-and-quasi).

Answer (score 1):

Recursive definition of A:

$ A := ab | aA | Ab $

Answer (score 0):

Since the strings have to start with $a$ and end with $b$, your base case isn't the empty string but $ab$. From there, your options are to add an $a$ or a $b$. If you add a character to a 2-character string, there are three places to put it: a the beginning, middle, or end. If you add an $a$ to $ab$, the beginning and middle are the same, and the end is not allowed, since that will create an instance of $ba$. Thus, you can consider the beginning to be the only place to put an $a$. Similarly, the only place to put a $b$ is at the end. This means that you end up with a string of $a$'s and $b$'s, with all of the $a$'s before the $b$'s. Every time you add an $a$, you can have to add it to the beginning (otherwise you would create an instance of $ba$), and every time you add a $b$, you have to add it to the end. So $A =\{ab, aS, Sb: S \in A\}$